# What happens in numpy's log function? Are there ways to improve the performance?

Tags: c#, python, matlab, performance, numpy

I have a computation project with heavy use of log function (for integers), billions of calls. I find the performance of numpy's log is surprisingly slow.

The following code takes 15 to 17 secs to complete:

```
import numpy as np
import time

t1 = time.time()
for i in range(1,10000000): 
    np.log(i)
t2 = time.time()
print(t2 - t1)
```

However, the math.log function takes much less time from 3 to 4 seconds.

```
import math
import time

t1 = time.time()
for i in range(1,10000000): 
    math.log(i)
t2 = time.time()
print(t2 - t1)
```

I also tested matlab and C#, which takes about 2 secs and just 0.3 secs respectively.

**matlab**

```
tic
for i = 1:10000000
    log(i);
end
toc
```

**C#**

```
var t = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 1; i < 10000000; ++i)
     Math.Log(i);
Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - t).TotalSeconds);
```

Is there any way in python that I can improve the performance of log function?

Comment: I am pretty interested in the answer. Specially because I just went in the source code, and the function is hard to trace. At the left of it tin the source code, it is written : `# real signature unknown; restored from __doc__`. Can anybody also explain how the source code works?

Comment: The answer seems to be in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650194/are-numpys-math-functions-faster-than-pythons?rq=1

Comment: `np.log` is optimised to work on arrays of values, not single values. For example `np.log(np.arange(1,10000000))` (log of array of integers in that range) takes about 120ms for me.

Comment: Just asked a friend of mine and he pointed out the overhead cost of `numpy`. Basically, `numpy` tests for various things before probably executing `math.log`.

Comment: You are unfairly comparing those functions when you're not using `np.log()` on arrays.

Comment: Maybe you can reformulate your problem and explain why you need to call `np.log()` that often instead of using vectorisation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NumPys functions are designed for arrays not for single values or scalars. They have a rather high overhead because they do several checks and conversions that will provide a speed benefit for big arrays but these are costly for scalars.

The conversion is really obvious if you check the type of the return:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import math

>>> type(np.log(2.))
numpy.float64
>>> type(math.log(2.))
float
```

On the other hand the `math`-module is optimized for scalars. So they don't need that many checks (I think there are only two: Convert to `float` and check is it's `<= 0`). Which is why `math.log` is faster **for scalars** compared to `numpy.log`.

But if you operate on arrays and want to take the logarithm of all elements in the array NumPy can be much faster. On my computer if I time the execution of `np.log` on an array compared to `math.log` of each item in a list then the timing looks different:

```
arr = np.arange(1, 10000000)
%timeit np.log(arr)
201 ms ± 959 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

lst = arr.tolist()
%timeit [math.log(item) for item in lst]
8.77 s ± 63.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So `np.log` will be many orders of magnitude faster on arrays (it's more than 40 times faster in this case)! And you don't need to write any loop yourself. As ufunc `np.log` will also correctly work on multidimensional numpy arrays and also allows to do the operation inplace.

As a rule of thumb: If you have an array with thousands of items NumPy will be faster, if you have scalars or only a few dozen items `math` + explicit loop will be faster.

---

Also don't use `time` for timing code. There are dedicated modules that give more accurate results, better statistics and disable garbage collection during the timings:

- [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) (built-in)
- [`perf`](https://github.com/haypo/perf) (extension package)

I generally use [`%timeit`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29280470/5393381) which is a convenient wrapper around the `timeit` functionality, but it requires [IPython](https://ipython.org/). They already conveniently display the result mean and deviation and do some (mostly) useful statistics like displaying the "best of 7" or "best of 3" result.

---

I recently analyzed the runtime behaviour of numpy functions for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43824239/5393381), some of the points also apply here.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, the issue of the python standard library being slow doesn't replicate on my machine (Windows 10, running Python 2.7.11 and numpy 1.11.0).

```
>>> t1 = time.time()
>>> for i in range(1,10000000): 
>>>     _ = np.log(i)
>>> t2 = time.time()
>>> print(t2 - t1)
9.86099982262
>>> t1 = time.time()
>>> for i in range(1,10000000): 
>>>     _ = math.log(i)
>>> t2 = time.time()
>>> print(t2 - t1)
2.48300004005
```

Similar to your performance in Matlab. @Nils raises a good point though, numpy is designed to be efficient on arrays.

```
>>> t1 = time.time()
>>> for i in range(1,1000): 
>>>     _ = np.log(np.arange(1,10000))
>>> t2 = time.time()
>>> print(t2 - t1)
0.146000146866
>>> t1 = time.time()
>>> for i in range(1,1000): 
>>>     _ = [math.log(i) for i in range(1,10000)]
>>> t2 = time.time()
>>> print(t2 - t1)
2.3220000267
```

If you can vectorize your input, numpy will outperform the standard math library and even come close to C#.