# Why is numpy ma.average 24 times slower than arr.mean?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, average, mean

I've found something interesting in Python's numpy. `ma.average` is a lot slower than `arr.mean` (arr is an array)

```
>>> arr = np.full((3, 3), -9999, dtype=float)
array([[-9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999.],
       [-9999., -9999., -9999.]])

%timeit np.ma.average(arr, axis=0)
The slowest run took 49.32 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 191 µs per loop

%timeit arr.mean(axis=0)
The slowest run took 6.63 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.41 µs per loop
```

with random numbers

```
arr = np.random.random((3,3))

%timeit arr.mean(axis=0)
The slowest run took 6.17 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.78 µs per loop

%timeit np.ma.average(arr, axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 186 µs per loop
```

--> That's nearly 24 times slower.

## Documentation

> [`numpy.ma.average(a, axis=None, weights=None, returned=False)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ma.average.html)
>
> Return the `weighted` average of array over the given axis.
>
> [`numpy.mean(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)
>
> Compute the arithmetic mean along the specified axis.

---

Why is `ma.average` so much slower than `arr.mean`? Mathematically they are the same (correct me if I'm wrong). My guess is that it has something to do with the weighted options on `ma.average` but shouldn't be there a fallback if no weights are passed?

Comment: [Masked operations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) (you see the ```.ma.```?) are slow!

Comment: Furthermore testing on small amounts of data is not a good practice: what is the difference between 7.78us en 186us? Not much. You need to use larger matrices.

Comment: ;) thanks, did not think about that. Anyway there is no mask on the given array.  found it in a older code that used to have a masked array there.

Comment: Does (probably) not matter. Different computation-model. Compare ```np.mean``` and ```np.average``` (two non-mask functions) and use bigger data!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem test it on a large amount in a project, it shortened the runtime of that part by 7.
7.78 to 186 can have a big impact if it's called often

Comment: @mumbala: I know that. I'm only saying that in future, you better publish results of tests on large batches. If here `ma.average` would redirect to `np.mean` (which it does not), even the redirection could have an enormous impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to find out why something is slower is to profile it. I'll use the 3rd party library [`line_profiler`](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) and the IPython command `%lprun` (see for example [this blog](http://pynash.org/2013/03/06/timing-and-profiling/)) here:

```
%load_ext line_profiler

import numpy as np
arr = np.full((3, 3), -9999, dtype=float)

%lprun -f np.ma.average np.ma.average(arr, axis=0)

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   519                                           def average(a, axis=None, weights=None, returned=False):
   ...
   570         1         1810   1810.0     30.5      a = asarray(a)
   571         1           15     15.0      0.3      m = getmask(a)
   572                                           
   573                                               # inspired by 'average' in numpy/lib/function_base.py
   574                                           
   575         1            5      5.0      0.1      if weights is None:
   576         1         3500   3500.0     59.0          avg = a.mean(axis)
   577         1          591    591.0     10.0          scl = avg.dtype.type(a.count(axis))
   578                                               else: 
   ...
   608                                           
   609         1            7      7.0      0.1      if returned:
   610                                                   if scl.shape != avg.shape:
   611                                                       scl = np.broadcast_to(scl, avg.shape).copy()
   612                                                   return avg, scl
   613                                               else:
   614         1            5      5.0      0.1          return avg
```

I removed some irrelevant lines.

So actually 30% of the time is spent in `np.ma.asarray` (something that `arr.mean` doesn't have to do!).

However the relative times change drastically if you use a bigger array:

```
arr = np.full((1000, 1000), -9999, dtype=float)

%lprun -f np.ma.average np.ma.average(arr, axis=0)
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   519                                           def average(a, axis=None, weights=None, returned=False):
   ...
   570         1          609    609.0      7.6      a = asarray(a)
   571         1           14     14.0      0.2      m = getmask(a)
   572                                           
   573                                               # inspired by 'average' in numpy/lib/function_base.py
   574                                           
   575         1            7      7.0      0.1      if weights is None:
   576         1         6924   6924.0     86.9          avg = a.mean(axis)
   577         1          404    404.0      5.1          scl = avg.dtype.type(a.count(axis))
   578                                               else:
   ...
   609         1            6      6.0      0.1      if returned:
   610                                                   if scl.shape != avg.shape:
   611                                                       scl = np.broadcast_to(scl, avg.shape).copy()
   612                                                   return avg, scl
   613                                               else:
   614         1            6      6.0      0.1          return avg
```

This time the `np.ma.MaskedArray.mean` function almost takes up 90% of the time.

Note: You could also dig deeper and look into `np.ma.asarray` or `np.ma.MaskedArray.count` or `np.ma.MaskedArray.mean` and check their line profilings. But I just wanted to show that there are lots of called function that add to the overhead.

So the next question is: did the relative times between `np.ndarray.mean` and `np.ma.average` also change? And at least on my computer the difference is much lower now:

```
%timeit np.ma.average(arr, axis=0)
# 2.96 ms ± 91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit arr.mean(axis=0)
# 1.84 ms ± 23.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

This time it's not even 2 times slower. I assume for even bigger arrays the difference will get even smaller.

---

This is also something that is actually quite common with NumPy:

The constant factors are quite high even for plain numpy functions (see for example my answer to the question ["Performance in different vectorization method in numpy"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43824239/5393381)). For `np.ma` these constant factors are even bigger, especially if you don't use a `np.ma.MaskedArray` as input. But even though the constant factors might be high, these functions excel with big arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much. There couldn't be a better answer! Also thanks for line_profiler with examples

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @WillemVanOnsem and @sascha in the comments above

**edit: applies to small arrays, see accepted answer for more information**

- Masked operations are slow try, to avoid it:

  ```
  mask = self.local_pos_history[:, 0] > -9
  local_pos_hist_masked = self.local_pos_history[mask]
  avg = local_pos_hist_masked.mean(axis=0)
  ```

  old with masked

  ```
  mask = np.ma.masked_where(self.local_pos_history > -9, self.local_pos_history)
  local_pos_hist_mask = self.local_pos_history[mask].reshape(len(self.local_pos_history) // 3, 3)
  avg_pos = self.local_pos_history
  ```
- np.average is nearly equal to arr.mean:

  ```
  %timeit np.average(arr, axis=0)
  The slowest run took 5.81 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
  100000 loops, best of 3: 9.89 µs per loop

  %timeit np.mean(arr, axis=0)
  The slowest run took 6.44 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
  100000 loops, best of 3: 8.74 µs per loop
  ```

just for clarification still a tests on small batch